# Is possible to write an object to browser cookie?

Tags: javascript

I want to pass an object from one window to another, what if its a complex object, it is possible to write it to cookie somehow? or only opening an saving a link to another window?

```
var link = window.open('url');
link.myVar = myObj;
```

or

```
document.cookie.set('someVar', myObj);
```

and in the other window:

```
document.cookie.get('someVar');
```

Comment: The best you have available is `JSON.stringify`, but keep in mind that it can't serialise things like functions or certain complex structures. It's good most of the time though.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies can only hold strings. They are designed to be transmitted in HTTP headers.

You can pass more complex data structures by encoding them as strings (e.g. with `JSON.stringify`), but a reference to another window is out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to pass an object from one window to another

You're on the right track with your code, but you're trying to give the window a reference to the object too soon. You could wait for it to load:

```
var link = window.open('url');
link.onload = function() {
    link.myVar = myOb;
};
```

The `load` event happens fairly late in the process, though, so I'd probably have the window that's being opened request the object as soon as it can:

```
// In the window being opened:
var myVar = opener.obj;
```

Rather than using the variable directly, I'd probably use a function to encapsulate that:

```
// In the window being opened:
var myVar = opener.getObject();
```

All of that will only work for windows in the *same origin*, which I assume they are if you're thinking about cookies. You can also use [cross-window messaging](http://www.w3.org/TR/webmessaging/) if the windows aren't in the same origin.

Just for completeness:

> Is possible to write an object to browser cookie?

Cookies can only contain strings. You can serialize your object using `JSON.stringify` or similar, but I wouldn't use cookies for cross-window messaging.